# How to convert CGPoint to Int?

Tags: ios, swift, int, cgpoint

I've set a `CGPoint` constant in my class of type `UIViewController`:

```
let point = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
```

This point constant is `CGPoint`, but I need it to be `Int`. Is there a way to convert `CGPoint` to `Int`?

Comment: CGPoint has x and y, how do you want to be Int?

Comment: maybe x and y coordinate in int points? is it possible?

Comment: @Isha Balla type caste to Int.

Comment: you can have let x = point.x and same as y but need to typecast

Comment: Thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CGPoint consists of two different values x, y of type `CGFloat`. So you need to convert both values to `Int`.

You can convert values as below:

```
let point = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
let x = Int(point.x)
let y = Int(point.y)
```

You will get x, y as Integer.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot get an `Int` value from a `CGPoint`, you can however get its x and y values as `Int`.

All you have to do is:

```
let x = Int(point.x)

let y = Int(point.y)
```